# Understanding atmospheric transmission's effect on IR camera

Tags: temperature, infrared-radiation, camera

I'm using an IR camera to view a person at 1 meter, and then 5 meters.  When I view them at 5 meters the max temperature I see for them drops by about 1 degree Fahrenheit. I assume this is because the air (humidity and gas) between my subject and the camera is attenuating the amount of thermal radiation that reaches the camera.

This camera says it receives infrared radiation in the 8-15 µm wavelength range. I am looking for a formula to calculate what this attenuation in free space is. Then I want to try to use that to correct for the change in temperature at different distances.

Comment: @Rob Jeffries : I believe sie is asking for a way to find out if, and if to calculate how much, thermal infrared (8-15 µm) light is absorbed by atmospheric gases over a given distance.

Comment: Yes that's it :)